# SSIS package not running on production but working on my local

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run ssis package on production server but its showing below error. Note that when I am running ssis package on local and trying to executing same file it works.

> Executed as user: ABC\XYZ. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 12.0.5000.0 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:11:55 AM  Error: 2017-05-30 04:11:56.17     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Script Task Script Task     Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.b__1a()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.MtaExecution.Run(Action action)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.CleanUp()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSTADenaliScriptProject(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.  To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.  Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.  To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].  End Error  Error: 2017-05-30 04:11:56.25     Code: 0x00000003     Source: Script Task      Description: The Script Task is corrupted.  End Error  Error: 2017-05-30 04:11:56.25     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Script Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:11:55 AM  Finished: 4:11:56 AM  Elapsed:  0.39 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am trying to importing 2 file one is `.csv` file and another `.xls` extension file. After importing file I am rechanging the name and then after moving the file on different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system cannot find the file specified" is the problem. If it runs in BIDS, that means you can navigate to that file path from your box, with your credentials. This error means you can't navigate to it from your SSIS box with the Proxy credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You have troubles with dll.
Add to GAC this assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core", Version=10.0.0.0 on your production server.

Full info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx

P.S. maybe you will need to rewrite dll, then use key /if

Comment: Not getting. how should I add assembly? Can u give me the proper steps to do so? Also what is the proper reason we need to do so?

Comment: You need to find find assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core", Version=10.0.0.0 on your LOCAL(or find it somwhere else), copy paste it to the remote server and add it to GAC using command "gacutil /if yourdllname.dll"
The reason to do it: your project is using some dll to do some work, but your remote server does not have this dll, so the project cant do its work.